# Android Sync Adapter - Cannot explicitly add accounts of type error

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I'm trying to create an Android Sync Adapter by following the Android Guides [here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Server-Synchronization-(SyncAdapter)).
However, it is returning the following error:

> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: uid 10081 cannot explicitly
>   add accounts of type: br.com.tarcisiofl.supply.syncaccount

**sync_adapter.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sync-adapter
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accountType="br.com.tarcisiofl.supply.syncaccount"
    android:contentAuthority="br.com.tarcisiofl.supply"
    android:userVisible="false"
    android:supportsUploading="false"
    android:allowParallelSyncs="false"
    android:isAlwaysSyncable="true"/>
```

**authenticator.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<account-authenticator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accountType="br.com.tarcisiofl.supply.syncaccount"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:smallIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
```

**AndroidManifest.xml** - Service and Provider

```
<service android:name=".repository.basicsyncadapter.AuthenticatorService2">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator2" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator2"
        android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
</service>

<provider
    android:name=".repository.basicsyncadapter.provider.SupplyProvider2"
    android:authorities="br.com.tarcisiofl.supply"
    android:exported="false"
    android:syncable="true" />
```

**AccountGeneral.java**

```
public class AccountGeneral {
    private static final String ACCOUNT_TYPE = "br.com.tarcisiofl.supply.syncaccount";
    private static final String ACCOUNT_NAME = "Supply";
}
```

Could someone point me out what is wrong?

Comment: Can you post the code where you actually create an account?